# VBA inserting new rows into a table with shifting the whole row of the sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code for inserting new rows into a table (also shifting down the content below the table), but it's using ActiveCell. Is it possible to use it for a defined sheet, table names and multiple rows like defined below the code.

```
With ActiveCell.ListObject
   ActiveSheet.Rows(.HeaderRowRange.Row + .ListRows.Count + 1).insert
   .Resize (ActiveSheet.Range(.HeaderRowRange(1, 1), Cells(.HeaderRowRange.Row + 
   .ListRows.Count + 1, .ListColumns.Count)))
End With

Set newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GeneralInfo")
tablename = "Table1"
newrows = 15
```

Comment: This might help: http://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/excel-vba-how-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-excel-table-with-vba-macro/

Comment: Where do you want the new rows? At the top of the ListObject? At the Bottom? Somewhere in between?

Answer (score 2):

First up, how do you find your ListObject? I generally use this syntax :

```
Range("Table1").ListObject
```

The Range("Table1") bit allows me to find the ListObject even if I don't know what sheet it's on. This works because Tables are also Named Ranges that you can address by name. So you just say "Go to the Named Range called Table1, and get me the ListObject that lives there". Otherwise you would need to know in advance what sheet the ListObject is on, and use the following:

```
Worksheets("SomeSheet").Listobjects("Table1")
```

...which works just fine until one day you move the Table to a different sheet, and forget to update your code.

Next, how to add rows? To add a single listrow, just use:

```
 Range("Table1").ListObject.ListRows.Add X
```

...where X is the ListRow number you want it to be added in above. Put 1 for the top, 2 for the second, and so on. Leave it blank and your ListRow gets added to the bottom.

But that only lets you add 1 ListRow at a time. So you've got three choices:

1. Create a loop, do it 15 times
2. Simply resize the ListObject so that 15 rows get added to the end
3. Just insert entire sheet rows at the position you want the new ListRows, using something like this:

   Rows("16:30").Insert Shift:=xlDown